# TFS 2010 File Merge error

Tags: tfs, merge-conflict-resolution

I have team of 20 working on different projects in TFS 2010. I have enabled both options of `multiple checkouts` and `Get latest on checkout`.

Couple of days back one of our developer started facing an issue. Issue is when they merge files, conflict occurs and they get resolved normally by selecting `Auto Merge` option. But some of these files aren't resolved and throw the following error.

> The following exception was encountered. NAMEOFFILE cannot be merged. Please retry with another resolution option.

When I see the conflict, It's different from others. Conflict type is `Writable file` and its description is `A writable file by the same name exists locally`

On these files, I only get 2 options, `Overwrite local file or folder` or `Keep local file contents`
If I select either of two options, developer lost the code.